# Unsafe member access on an `any` value, for a typed object

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Hitting a TypeScript error I can't figure out

I have a DateRange model defined as

```
export interface DateRange {
  from: { year: number, month: number, day: number },
  to: { year: number, month: number, day: number }
}
```

and then I have a method which takes in one as a parameter

```
dateRangeSelected(value: DateRange)
```

Then my intellisense works properly as a type value dot from dot year it all shows up as expected, but I'm getting a lint error when access its members

[image]

```
value.from.year
```

results in an error that

> Unsafe member access .from on an `any` value

1. How can I resolve this error, where might my typing issue be...

---

Per suggestion below I tested and found that when defining interface from the same component instead of exporting it works...

Could it be my import statement?

```
import DateRangePicker, { DateRange } from
    '../components/DateRangePicker.vue';
```

The component has a default export for its component

```
export default MyComponent { ... }
export interface DateRange { ... }
```

Comment: Somehow your `value.from` seems to be getting typed as `any`, but your code seems to work fine as is https://tsplay.dev/NlpaQN. So the issue lies in some code that you haven't posted.

Comment: When I test it from the same component instead of exporting you're right it works...    Could it be my import statement? `import DateRangePicker, { DateRange } from '../components/DateRangePicker.vue';` ? The component has a default export for its component `export default MyComponent` and then `export interface DateRange`

Comment: Oh you're importing this from a `.vue` file? I don't know much about Vue, but typically typescript can only get types from `.ts` or `.tsx` files. It sounds like it's having a hard time treating that `.vue` file like a typescript file.

Comment: Try to move a type to .ts file and see what happens. Since .vue is not standardized and primarily aimed at SFC and the use of default export, the support of named exports varies between tools. And there's another level of uncertainty with named types. The compiler, IDE and linter - all of them have chances to behave differently in this regard. Also make sure you have script lang=ts.